# How do I kill the merchant in the "Port Authority" mission without being detected?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

One of Ezio's assassinations requires me to kill a merchant hiding on a boat without being detected by any of his guards.

He's being guarded by an archer on the dock (no problem), two patrolling guards on the back of the boat (no problem), two stationary guards near the wheel (kind of a problem), and two heavy guards right in front of him (huge problem).

**What strategy, tool, or combination do I need to use to off this guy?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I eventually succeeded at it.

[image]

1. Jump down from the roof, kill the guy on the dock from the water.
2. Climb up onto the rear of the ship, kill the patrolling guard when he comes by.
3. Same thing, different guard.
4. Hop off the ship, climb down, pull this guard, climb back up.
5. Wait for guard 7 to be walking away, then kill this guard...
6. ...and this one at the same time, with the double assassinate skill.
7. Here's the tricky part.  Jump back over the side of the boat and wait until this guard is walking away.  Pickup the body of guard 5 and toss him overboard.  Go back over the side.  Wait.  Do it again for guard 6.  This time, *allow guard 7 to spot you before you go over the side*.  He'll go into suspicious (yellow) mode and walk over to investigate the spot where you were.  There won't be any bodies so he won't go into alert, and you can haul him over the side.
8. Now that you have free run of the rear of the ship, hop up onto the rail and air assassinate.

Comment: Man this took forever.

Comment: I managed to do a simpler variation to this without the tricky step 7. It is the same, except I killed guard 7 before the double kill. This was accompllished by jumping on the poop deck (heh) and be spotted by "guard 7". When he came to investigate, I hung from the ledge and pulled him down. This leaves you do do the double kill without having to time the patrol.

Comment: How do you assassinate guards 5 and 6 at the same time? Every time I've tried, it's either up close and only one is assassinated (alerting the other and ending the mission), or it's from a distance (or from atop the steering wheel) and it's a flashy air double-assassination that alerts the other guards (or even just the target), ending the mission.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [this post](http://www.gamespot.com/assassins-creed-ii/answers/sequence-13-port-authority-mission-help-169445/):

> 1) Dive into the water, either from the rooftop directly (move along
>   the roof to the right of the mission start-point) or work your way
>   down to ground level
>
> 2) Swim to the other side of the boat- DO NOT get too close to the
>   boat until you are round the other side
>
> 3) Climb up the hull to the right-hand side section of rigging just
>   until you are able to grab the top railing
>
> 4) Shimmy across until you are towards the back of the boat, just
>   behind the 2 guards that are over-looking your target
>
> 5) Wait until all patrolling guards are away from you (you can try and
>   ledge assassinate some, one of my friends said this worked however it
>   did not work for me)
>
> 6) Climb up and immediately drop onto the deck
>
> 7) IMMEDIATELY drop a smoke bomb- you should have time to do this just
>   before you are spotted
>
> 8) Run past all guards, jump onto the rail above your target, and air
>   assassinate him... DONE!

Alternatively, as user [bobbyrk puts it](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/956858-assassins-creed-ii/53562862):

> The way I did it, was first to swim around the front side of the boat,
>   away from the dock. Climb up the side of the boat, and when the first
>   guard gets to the back left corner of the boat, pull him over the
>   edge.
>
> You don't have enough time to slide over and pull the second rear
>   guard overboard, so don't bother trying. The guard on the dock will
>   return, you have to be about three meters from the rear of the boat
>   for him to not see you when he reaches his stopping point at the end
>   of the dock. When he turns and walks away, monkey over to the back of
>   the boat, take out the second rear guard, then jump to the dock, and
>   use the gun to take out the dock guard. That'll draw the attention of
>   the brutes and the guards at the front of the boat if you time it
>   right.
>
> Get back in the water, and climb over to the left front side of the
>   boat, near the forward stopping point of the patrolling guard on that
>   side. When he gets there, pull him overboard. Repeat that process for
>   the other patrolling guard. Don't bother with the two guards in the
>   front end of the boat.
>
> Circle to the back end of the boat, climb up and walk slowly up behind
>   the two guards in front of the wheel. Walk between them so you stab
>   both at once, and you'll be free to take the target out.

Comment: This mission was a pain in the butt.  Thanks for the help, these descriptions gave me the idea for the method that finally worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone made this mission harder than it had to be...

Climb the back left wall of the ship. Off the ledge, drop a smoke bomb. Move into position behind the 2 guards in front of the ledge above the target and drop a 2nd smoke bomb. Climb the ledge, then jump down for the assassination.

Piece of cake.

Comment: I totally should have tried that.

Comment: Just GREAT! Thanks! :D I'ts the second time around this game and i did not have the patience!

Answer (score 2):

ALTERNATIVE: GUN!! 
I found it very difficult to assassinate them all with a blade. Instead, I tried a gun assault.

First step: swim around the boat and wait for the one on the dock to get to the end of the pier, when for a moment he is facing away and looking out at the water. At the right moment quickly climb onto the pier and assassinate him from behind with the hidden blade.

Second step: sneak back up the stairs and assassinate the two guarding the stairs down to the boat from behind.

Third step: go to the bottom of the stairs and get just close enough to lock on to a guard, and assassinate him with the gun.

Fourth step: they will get suspicious and one will probably come up the stairs looking for you. Just run back into the city streets and stay out of his line of site until he turns back towards the boat. When he turns to head back to the boat assassinate him from behind.

Fifth step: continue locking onto a guard from the dock and shooting him, then run away and kill the suspicious one again as in step four.

Continue step five until you hit the target (when I did it he became suspicious and came to the side of the boat so I just shot him :D) or until you take out all the guards. MUCH easier! You're welcome :P

Answer (score 1):

I got the easiest answer, get down to the bottom of the stairs without bothering the 2 guards guarding. Then pull out your gun and shoot the guy patroling the dock, eventually some of the guards will come down to the docks and check. Shoot them too. After that the merchant should come down and check the shooting site then you just have to shoot or stab him from the water.

Answer (score 0):

My way was simple enough. Just do a double air assassination on the two guards at the top of the stairs, then once the sock guard is standing at the side of the boat use a pistol to gun him down the quickly dive into the water from the top of the staircase, this strategy is genius because both brutes and most guards will check it out and the funny thing is, one brute will fall into the water trust me it works I did it five times.

Now that their busy climbonto the rear of the boat( sometimes this may not be necessary because sometimes the rear guards will go to the staircase) then once the two rear guards are taken out shimmy to take out the patrolling left guard because the right is gone.

Once that's done just do a double kill on the two rear stationary guards then do an air assassination for the target. P.s I forgot to mention that you should climb onto the docks at the rear of the ships and it's best to have full ammo so you can shoot the guards that left the ship, do this after step one.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone still needs this, I used the gun to kill the guard on the docks, and then shot one on the boat, after the chaos the boss was standing on the dock with one of the brute soldiers. I swam up behind them and assassinated them with the hidden blade, it made things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tries, I got an easy way. Not easy, but easier.
Kill the two patrolling guards above in the way everyone is saying. Then kill the patrolling guard on the back side of the ship. The side towards the canal/river.
Climb up the back of the ship, and poison one of the two stationary guards. Climb back down. Now, climb up the side of the ship and wait for all guards to go to the poisoned guard to watch his antics.
Climb up the ship, they will all become curious instantly. Immediately kill the merchant.